# Java syntax error on tokens, misplaced constructs - array initialization

Tags: java, arrays, syntax-error, array-initialization

I have the following code in Java 5:

```
for (Object o : theList) {
    for (int k=0; k<theList.size(); k++)
        int[][] m = new int[7][7];
    m = theList.get(k);
    for (int i=0; i<7; i++) {
        for (int j=0; j<7; j++) {
            System.out.println(m[i][j]);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    System.out.println();
}
...
}
```

On the line with

```
int[][] m = new int[7][7]
```

it is telling me "Syntax error on token(s), misplaced construct(s)". Any idea what I'm doing wrong?
Thanks.

Comment: Nevermind. My error was in missing the { on the second line. Oops.

Comment: Your code is highly unlikely to do what you want, anyway. The lines `int[][] m = new int[7][7]; m = theList.get(k);` create an empty int[][] array and then **immediately throw it away** so that `m` starts referring to the value from the list instead. Please read about reference vs. value semantics.

Comment: I suggest you use the code formatter in your IDE, This would show up this bug immediately. i.e. don't do the layout yourself, let the IDE do it.

Comment: `>` is for quoting, four spaces is for code.